# Change a default window size in browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, forms, popup

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <textarea name="mess" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input name="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

After pressing the button "submit", brouwser will open a new window with some text like "OK, your messagw sent to our mailbox".

Can I make this "new" window NOT fullsize of browser, but 400x300 resolution.

(also i have "mail.php" file with the next code:

```
<?php
if (isset ($mess))
{
$mess = substr($mess,0,10000);
if (empty($mess))
{
echo "<center><b>Message written<p>";
echo "<a href=back-form.html>Go back and make all steps correctly</a>";
exit;
}
}
else 
{
$mess = "Unspecified";
}
$i = "не указано";
if ( $mess == $i)
{
echo "Error! The script does not have to pass parameters!";
exit;
}
$to = "vitelp@gmail.com";  /*адрес*/
$subject = "Message to your website";
$message = "Message:$mess";
mail ($to,$subject,$message) or print "Cant send your letter!";
echo "<center><b>Thanks for ypur attention.";
exit;
?>
```

)

Comment: Just bear in mind that many of us prevent just this sort of behavior, as we use tabs, not windows. The modern way of doing this is with an asynch javascript and a "modal" div that are part of the same (current) window. My browsers do not allow you to open new windows nor to resize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a new window with javascript check out `window.open()` method here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `onload` function in the new window:

```
<body onload="resizeTo(400,300)">
```

`400` is the width, `300` is the height.

**Note:** `resizeTo()` isn't supported by all major browsers. More info at [w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp).

Comment: It resize ALL BROWSER with ALL windows, i need to resize only the new opened window.

Comment: @TRAVA: It should resize *only* the current window, and does so for me in Firefox. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the target of your form to a new window set you opened with javascript before:

```
myForm.onsubmit = function(){
   var w = window.open('about:blank','Popup_Window','width:200,height:200');
   myForm.target = 'Popup_Window';
}
```